# Remove "ServiceStack" mentions from licensed services/APIs

Tags: servicestack

Albeit I have no problem advertising and promoting ServiceStack in general. I have a project that requires that I remove ServiceStack mentions from my APIs' Response Headers:

[image]

And also from myservice/types:

[image]

Like I said my team all has licenses to develop with ServiceStack...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it from your AppHost’s HostConfig:

```
Config.GlobalResponseHeaders.Remove(“X-Powered-By”);
```

Comment: Thanks @mythz, How about the ServiceStack in myservice/types anyway to remove that?

Comment: @BrianOgden Not sure what you’re referring to, but Types can’t be changed and the generated c# DTOs require a dependency to the impl/dep-free ServiceStack.Interfaces which can’t be changed